# How to delete a row from a custom ListView when user clicks on a button inside that row

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created a custom listview and populated it with data, But am finding it hard to delete a row with a button placed inside that same row. Below is the code for the adapter. How can I delete this row. Any ideas ??

```
public Pursue_results_listview_adapter(Context c, String[] ClientName,
        String[] clientId) {
    super(c, R.layout.pursuing_list_row, R.id.client, ClientName);
    this.context = c;
    this.clientIdArray = clientId;
    this.ClientNameArray = ClientName;
}

class viewHolder {
    TextView client;
    ImageView deleteclient;

    public viewHolder(View v) {

        deleteclient = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.deleteclient);
        client = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.client);

    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    viewHolder holder = null;
    if (row == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.pursuing_list_row, parent, false);
        holder = new viewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (viewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    final String clientid = cleintIdArray[position];

    holder.client.setText(ClientNameArray[position]);

    holder.deleteclient.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //delete client

                           notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
holder.deleteclient.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        int index = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString())
        data.remove(index); //where 'data' is your list
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the position in the tag like `setTag(position)` and in `onClick` remove the position like

```
Integer i= (Integer) view.getTag();
list.remove(i.intValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, Also is there any reason you aren't using some sort of collection to hold your data? It would make the it much simpler.

Firstly making clientIdArray and clientNameArray into Arraylists

```
Arraylist<String> clientIdArray;
Arraylist<String> clientNameArray;
```

then change this

```
this.clientIdArray = clientId;
this.ClientNameArray = ClientName;
```

to

```
this.clientIdArray = new Arraylist<String>(Arrays.asList(clientId));
this.ClientNameArray = new Arraylist<String>(Arrays.asList(ClientName));
```

And then your code becomes this

```
//Store the index that is being deleted in this views tag
holder.deleteclient.setTag(position)
holder.deleteclient.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        //get the index back
        int index = (Integer)v.getTag();

        //Removal code goes here, if you don't want to make your arrays into arraylists 
        //you will need to write your own removal code
        clientIdArray.remove(index);
        ClientNameArray.remove(index);

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: they are in an arraylists, i created the adapter as a separate class

Comment: I would recommend passing them to, and storing them in the adapter as Arraylists as well then.